# How to populate a linear layout using arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a linear layout which contains multiple widgets. I want to populate it using an `ArrayList`. I don't want to use use a listview because it didn't work in scrollview.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_xxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="jshadb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_xxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="464.89" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_xxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should just iterate over your array and use `yourLinearLayout.addView(item);`

Comment: inflate layout by using `LayoutInflater`

Comment: any example how to do it.....will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the way

```
LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
linf = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this);

//Linear Layout on you want to add inflated View
 LinearLayout tbl_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layoutid);

 for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

       View v = linf.inflate(R.layout.YourLinearLayout, null);//Pass your lineraLayout

      ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.xxxx)).setText("textS");

        tbl_layout.addView(v);
    }
```